# Cross-domain POST request with CORS returns access-control-allow-origin is missing

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cors, cross-domain

I want to perfrom cross-domain request from localhost to localhost:81, but I constantly get CORS-Header'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing. But I have set the header in postHere.php. I also tried header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); and it is also not working?

postHere.php

```html
<?php
switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) {
    case 'http://localhost':
    case 'https://localhost':
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
        break;
}
```

HTML file  in localhost from which I want to send to localhost:81

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:81/postHere.php',
            crossDomain: true,
            data: '{"some":"json"}',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var value = responseData.someKey;
            },
            error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('POST failed.');
            }
        });
    </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should enable your server on the second origin (in your case `localhost:81`, though you should probably use `8081` instead) to allow cross-origin requests. Check mozilla guides on that.

Links:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS